# wish someone to do

Tags: meaning

This construction is controversial "**wish someone to do**". If it was completely ineligible then it would be easy, because it would be expedient not to use it at all. But there are some contexts in which it works. Could you explain when it is fit to be used and when it isn't.

**The wrong ones:**

> I wish you to have good luck.
>
> She wished him to get better.

**The correct ones:**

> We must consider the facts as they are, not as we would wish them to
> be.​
>
> If you wish someone to manage your investments…​
>
> I wouldn’t wish her to think we didn’t care.

What is that fine line between the correct and wrong usage?

Comment: By the way, even the correct usages here are a bit old-fashioned. It might be more common in casual speech to use "want" instead of "wish" when we're not using hypothetical tenses: "I wish you would go away," but "I want you to go away."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your 'correct' examples are all about 'wanting someone to do something' or 'wanting something good to happen to you'. Your 'incorrect' ones are about 'giving someone good wishes in the hope that something good will happen to them'.

The idiomatic versions:

> I wish you [good] luck. (I hope you will have it.)
>
> She wished him a speedy recovery. (She hoped he would get better soon.)

Comment: And to add a bit of detail, the problem with \**She wished him to get better* is that getting better is being seen as not entirely within his control. Contrast that with *She wished him to get some milk at the market*, which is fine.

Comment: But this one is OK "She wished for him to get better"?

Comment: Ye-es - but it could suggest that she wanted him to get better for her own reasons rather than  offering good wishes to him.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum Interesting. That's a different contrast than the one Kate found, but both track. I wonder if one is the actual differentiation while the other is an emergent property.

Comment: @gotube - I don't see it as different. You wish for something on another's behalf _because_ the result is outside your or their control.